Flutter - AnimatedSwitcher causes jerky text
I'm currently working on recreating a design from a video by Benjamin Code. To accomplish this, I'm using a Dart package called AnimatedSwitcherPlus which provides pre-made animations similar to what I'm aiming for.
I'm specifically animating a Text element using AnimatedSwitcherPlus.translationLeft. The animation looks smooth, but I've noticed an occasional stutter, particularly near the end, where the Text seems to slightly shift. In my scenario, it occurs when the variable year changes to "1977".
Here's the code snippet:
AnimatedSwitcherPlus.translationLeft(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
  child: Text(
    year.substring(2, 3),
    style: GoogleFonts.kanit(
      fontSize: 200,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      color: const Color(0xFFE4DA7C),
    ),
    key: ValueKey(year.substring(2, 3)),
  ),
),

Remember the following text:
year: It is a string that looks like this: "1980". It is updated using setState(() {}) somewhere in the full code. If you need the full code of the design I'm trying to recreate, please ask and I'll post it.
If you need more information, feel free to ask in the comments section. Thanks in advance for your help!
